# Sign ambiguity in the transition from Minkowski space to Euclidean space

Tags: special-relativity, metric-tensor, conventions, wick-rotation

In the metric convention $(+,-,-,-)$, the spacetime interval is given by $$x^2=x_\mu x^\mu=(x^0)^2-|\textbf{x}|^2=t^2-|\textbf{x}|^2$$ in the units $c=1$. To make the theory Euclidean one considers the change of variable $t\to i\tau$ whic makes the interval $$x^2=-\tau^2-|\textbf{x}|^2=-(\tau^2+|\textbf{x}|^2).\tag{1}$$ But the Euclidean distance is taken as $x^2=\tau^2+|\textbf{x}|^2$. What happens to the minus sign in (1)?

Comment: What if I choose (convention you call it) as space time interval                       $$                         x^2=x_\mu x^\mu=-(x^0)^2+|\textbf{x}|^2=-t^2+|\textbf{x}|^2  $$

Comment: @Frobenius In that metric convention, it works. What about the convention I chose?

Comment: I think that the main here is your effort to see Minkowski space as Euclidean space. This is impossible because of the indefinite and positive definite  of the metric.. That's why I find also the term transition inappropriate in this case.

Comment: @Frobenius This is a widely used trick to perform and make sense of certain integrals. Also used in finding Euclidean solutions of several classical field equations such as instantons.

Comment: in the metric that you used, the Euclidean distance would be $-\vert x\vert^2$.  (sorry can't get the boldface $x$ to work.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Do you mean $x^2=-x_E^2$ where $x_E^2=\tau^2+|\textbf{x}|^2$?

Comment: @SRS : yes, exactly.  If you want $x^2=+x^2_E$ you need to use the $(-+++)$ metric so the space component come out as +.  If this is what you want I'll write it up as an answer.

Comment: Just cut-and-pasted our short discussion as an answer.  Be well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If one uses the metric $(+---)$ then the Euclidean distance would be $-\vert x^2\vert_E$, i.e. $\vert x\vert^2=-\vert x\vert^2_E$.  To get the usual Euclidean distance one needs to use the $(-+++)$: as the space components are not affected by the introduction of the imaginary unit, one ought to choose a metric where the space components has the same sign as in the Euclidean distance.